# Javascript - Loading Images from Dropbox returns 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am attempting to load a series of Images from a Shared Dropbox Folder like so:

```
function getSprite(raw) {
    var sprt = new Image();
    sprt.crossOrigin = '';
    sprt.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/k1v7iv85vntx107/AABOD-CfE3A5sQo0RPPmRmmJa/ground1.png' + (raw ? '?raw=1' : '');
    return sprt;
}
```

The folder is shared, and Dropbox says that 'People with Link can View'. I have tried to do the same with Google Drive, but I get a Cross Origin Error there.

EDIT: I just tried to share one of the files individually, and it worked. DO I have to now go through and do this for each file in the folder? I thought If I just share the folder I should have access to all its contents.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
GET https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/k1v7iv85vntx107/AABOD-CfE3A5sQo0RPPmRmmJa/characters/triggerman/up.png?raw=1 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a name before the ".png" extension? If you put the value of `sprt.src` into your browser manually, can you see the image?

Comment: Um, the src line above makes no sense... Why is there a comma? (guessing typo). Where are you getting a cross origin error? Loading an image does not cause that.

Comment: Yeah those were typos. The error occurs when I try to edit the image data. But dropbox doesnt even let me load an image at all. When I manually put the URL into my browser, I still get a 403, is there an issue with dropbox?

Comment: Have you tried using the "public" folder inside your Dropbox account?

Comment: How are you producing this url? You should take the link from "Share" button, and replace `https://www.dropbox.com/s/` part with `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/`

Comment: I created the link by pressing share on the folder. Once I get the link then I do what you suggested. Here is the link I get: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k1v7iv85vntx107/AABOD-CfE3A5sQo0RPPmRmmJa?dl=0

Comment: No I meant the "Share" button of each individual file.

Comment: I have around 80 files in that folder. So there is no way to load them from a  shared folder?

Comment: Drop the entire folder into your Public folder.

Comment: @Amadan, no the cross-enabled url is per file, no way to get it on an entire folder, in free mode at least.

Comment: Public Folders have been disabled by dropbox and they suggest to use the share links instead. Also If I want to create a public folder I need a subscription to Dropbox Pro.

Comment: Ok Damn. So what is an alternative? Google Drive has the same problem.

Comment: @user3024235: Hmm, my Public still works. Maybe as a legacy user, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah they said accounts that existed before 2012 or something still have them. Looks liek using my own server is the only way.

Comment: Or to click on the 80 "share" links in this folder.

Comment: You can make a Dropbox App e try to access the app folder files thought some library, like dropbox.js!  Also, take a look at the dropbox HTTP interface: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue

Comment: The problem is that I need it to be accessible and simple so that users can upload their own folders and use them on my site.

Comment: They will have to upload their files individually then. You can do the parsing of the string with js.

Comment: Have you asked this on their help site?

Comment: I found it on an FAQ that we cant use public folders. I will post something on their forum. Right now im thinking I should just post a zip file on dropbox and then download it and unzip it.

Comment: Using their API seems to be the best choice, you can upload photos from your App!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the original shared link you had was:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k1v7iv85vntx107/AABOD-CfE3A5sQo0RPPmRmmJa?dl=0

This is a shared link for a folder. Note that you can't just modify it directly to get shared links for individual files inside that folder though, which is what you appear to be trying in your question.

To get the individual files, you have a few options:

1. Manually get the shared links for each file via the Dropbox web site, as you mentioned.
2. Use the API to individually but programmatically get shared links for each file: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings
3. Use the API to download the files in the original shared link by specifying the path inside the folder: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file This is likely closest to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has much to do with JavaScript. Go Incognito and take a look at it because all I can see is a [403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIM3t.png) from my browser.

Comment: Yeah thats when I try to go through the folder sharing link, it works when I share the individual file, but thats not what I need.